# Laravel passport with laravel 10x driver passport error

Tags: laravel-passport, laravel-10

I use laravel passport with laravel 10x and has a error when use oauth2.
In config/auth.php:

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users'
        ]
    ],
```

When i use route /oauth/authorize. I have a error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsXaf.png)

Please helpe me!

I go to the core of laravel passport and i found this code

```
public function __construct(AuthorizationServer $server,
                                StatefulGuard $guard,
                                AuthorizationViewResponse $response)
    {
        $this->server = $server;
        $this->guard = $guard;
        $this->response = $response;
    }
```

The guards.api is not StatefulGuard.